# JDK7 Files.copy

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream, java-7

In the OpenJDK7 project [java.nio.file.Files](http://www.docjar.com/src/api/java/nio/file/Files.java), there is the following function. My question is, should the while loop condition be >= instead of >? This is because the source.read javadoc says that when EOF is reached, it'll return -1 and not 0.

```
/**
 * Reads all bytes from an input stream and writes them to an output stream.
 */
private static long copy(InputStream source, OutputStream sink)
    throws IOException
{
    long nread = 0L;
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n;
    while ((n = source.read(buf)) > 0) {
        sink.write(buf, 0, n);
        nread += n;
    }
    return nread;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong read function.
The read function of InputStream that takes a byte array will return the number of bytes that have been copied into the buffer. So you can know how many bytes you can then copy out of it.

```
 * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
 *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
 *             the stream has been reached.
```

So it does cover both cases: end of stream reached (-1) or no bytes read into the buffer for any other reason.

Comment: The javadoc of the function says that it'll read all bytes from the input stream. If it's on a poor connection and the next byte may not be immediately available, the while loop will end before fetching all bytes. Isn't it so?

Comment: @tanyehzheng That's incorrect. The javadocs for [`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) say that at least one byte will be returned, otherwise it will block. If the first byte can't be read for any reason besides EOF, then it throws an `IOException`. Any stream that returns 0 for this function is incorrectly written and doesn't subclass `InputStream` properly. (Except when the buffer is a zero-length array, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a bug or not depends on the intent of the function.

Normally this will work exactly as you expect since the call to `read` will block until at least one byte of data becomes available. However, if the input stream is non-blocking, the `read` call will return 0 when there is *currently* no more data available. This state is different from the stream being actively closed.

In other words, one could argue that this is a bug or not, depending on what you expect it to do when faced with a non-blocking stream that has no data available at the moment the method is called.

Comment: if the condition is changed to >= 0, then no matter it's in blocking or non-blocking mode, it'll work as expected. Isn't it?

Comment: That depends of what you expect. Do you want it to block when there is no more data available? Also, if you do, and the stream is non-blocking, you'll end up consuming 100% CPU while waiting for the next byte of data. That's not very good.

Answer (score 1):

Same, because `InputStream.read(byte[])` here won't return 0. From javadoc

> at least one byte is read